# Реверс изображения с помощью CSS с сохранением той же позиции

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, svg

Вот пример кода:     `https://codepen.io/yury-leonov/pen/rZxxQE`

```js
$(".example").on("click", function(e){
  $(e.target).toggleClass("reverse");
})
```

```css
.reverse{
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 700px;height: 700px;margin-left: 100px">
    <svg viewBox="-200 0 700 700">
        <image class="example" href="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6f/3d/6a/6f3d6aab605e25af947d804c4a2cb558.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" x="50", y="50"/>
        <image class="example" href="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6f/3d/6a/6f3d6aab605e25af947d804c4a2cb558.jpg" width="150px" height="100px" x="100", y="0"/>
      <!--x value can be changed during time-->
    </svg>
</div>
```

**Проблема:**

При вращении стрелка перемещается из своего положения.

**Ожидаемое:**

Стрелка должна оставаться там же. Необходимо сделать на основе `css` (без `js`, вычисляющего конечное значение `x`)

**PS:**

Применение `translateX (- ??? px)` - не является вариантом, потому что может быть много объектов, которые должны вращаться.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [SVG. Reverse image using css. Keep image at the same place](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52131952/7394871) от участника  [@Yuriy Leonov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4436022/yuriy-leonov).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/52131952/7394871

Answer (score 6):

Используйте `transform-origin` and `transform-box`

```js
$(".example").on("click", function(e){
  $(e.target).toggleClass("reverse");
})
```

```css
.reverse{
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform-origin: center;
    transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 700px;height: 700px;margin-left: 100px">
    <svg viewBox="-200 0 700 700">
        <image class="example" href="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6f/3d/6a/6f3d6aab605e25af947d804c4a2cb558.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" x="50", y="50"/>
        <image class="example" href="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6f/3d/6a/6f3d6aab605e25af947d804c4a2cb558.jpg" width="150px" height="100px" x="100", y="0"/>
      <!--x value can be changed during time-->
    </svg>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [SVG. Reverse image using css. Keep image at the same place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52132557/7394871) от участника  [@Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson).</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Можно сделать  мини анимацию персонажей,- девушки и парня.

Их изображения будут поворачиваться, отворачиваться друг от друга. Возможны другие варианты. На мой взгляд это должно выглядеть довольно интересно.

*Этот вариант решения может иметь и практическое применение, когда иконки .png поворачиваются и осуществляется, какое-то действие.*

**Поворот туда-сюда каждого изображения после клика на выбранном изображении.**

```js
$(".example").on("click", function(e){
  $(e.target).toggleClass("reverse");
})
```

```css
.reverse{
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform-origin: center;
    transform-box: fill-box;
}
.container {
 width:50%;
 height:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" >
    <svg viewBox="0 0 700 700">
        <image class="example" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM5im.png" width="300px" height="450px" x="50", y="50"/>
        <image class="example" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFoj1.jpg" width="300px" height="450px" x="350", y="0"/>
   </svg>
</div>
```

Приложение адаптивно и работает во всех современных браузерах, кроме **IE**

Источник ответа:@Alexandr_TT

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [SVG. Reverse image using css. Keep image at the same place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52256501/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>